# Simulating data: Two groups with different intercept but same coefficient

Tags: r, simulation

I've spend the day trying to figure out how to simulate my desired data - with no luck. I hope you can help me! 
I am looking for a way to replicate this plot:

[image]

Thus, I am looking for a way to simulate around 200 observations divided in two groups with same coefficient but different intercept. How is this done?

Comment: please provide some sample data, and  try to better explain what you need help with - is it the question of how to plot  your fitted model?

Comment: Where's the simulation in this?  Are you generating these values (in which case show your effort), or are you asking how to get a single regression fit that captures both the red and green lines (use an [indicator variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)) for red/green)?  The latter can be generalized to k-1 indicators for k categories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simulate a normal distribution with a particular mean and distribute this around some function of `x`. Here I have done so for

- y = 5 - x + ϕ
- y = 10 - x + ϕ
- y = 15 - x + ϕ

Where ϕ is just a sample from a standard normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation 1:

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.3

set.seed(69)

x <- seq(0, 5, length.out = 100)
y1 <- rnorm(100, 5) - x 
y2 <- rnorm(100, 15) - x
y3 <- rnorm(100, 10) - x
groupings <- rep(c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3"), each = 100)
df <- data.frame(x = rep(x, 3), y = c(y1, y2, y3), groupings)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = groupings)) + 
  geom_point() +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) -x + 5, colour = "red") +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) -x + 10, colour = "blue") +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) -x + 15, colour = "forestgreen")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>